# The distance from the center to the perimeter of a square, given an angle theta

Tags: trigonometry

Given a square with some width w, and an angle theta, what's the distance d from the center to the perimeter?

Letting $r=w/2$, we clearly have $d=r$ at $\theta = \frac{n\pi}{2}$, and $d=\sqrt{2}r$ at $\theta=\frac{n\pi}{2}+\frac{\pi}{4}$.

But I can't figure out the general formula for any $\theta$
[image: Sample image]

Comment: $\frac{r}{\cos{\theta}}$ for ${\theta} < \frac{pi}{4}$?

Comment: yes it is correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will be periodic in $\theta$ because of the symmetric nature of this problem. Now, to answer the question, you have the right idea. but you can take it a step further by using trigenometric functions. We can see that:

$\cos(\theta) = \frac{\frac{w}{2}}{d} = \frac{w}{2d}$

when $\theta$ is in the range $[-\frac{\pi}{4}, \frac{\pi}{4}]$. Solving for d we get:

$d = \frac{w}{2\cos(\theta)} = \frac{r}{\cos(\theta)}$.

This is the same result @user4815162342 got. But to take it a step further, this is periodic in $\theta$. So, we can get a better answer that $d = \frac{r}{\cos(\phi)}$ where $\phi = \theta+k\frac{\pi}{2}$ where $k$ is some integer such that phi is inside the range we discussed earlier.

Comment: Try "where $\phi\equiv\theta \bmod \frac\pi2$ and $|\phi|\leq\frac\pi4.$"

Comment: I saw my error lol, was fixing as you wrote @DavidK

Comment: Yes, I see you fixed it while I was typing.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @DavidK, revision comments are much appreciated! :)